# Configuring pytest rootdir?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I've got a project with the following directory structure:

```
.
..
core/start.py
tests/test_curve.py
pytest.ini
```

The contents of pytest.ini are:

```
[pytest]
testpaths = tests
```

The contents of `test_curve.py` are:

```
import core.start

def test_curve():
    assert some_valid_stuff
```

When I run pytest in the project root folder, I get:

```
import core.start
ImportError: No module named 'core'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is not pytest issue, but python imports.
`core` and `tests` are not from the same package so you can not do `import core.start` either `from ..core import start`

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `PYTHONPATH` before running the tests:

```
PYTHONPATH=`pwd` pytest
```

Or install the code in developer's mode:

```
pip install -e .
pytest
```

Or run the tests in a virtual environment where the code is installed:

```
virtualenv mycode
. mycode/bin/activate
pip install .
pytest
deactivate
```

Or use [tox](/questions/tagged/tox) to create/activate/deactivate such virtual environments automatically.

Comment: Or, use `python -m pytest`.

Comment: +1, as @nn0p said, use `python -m pytest` as module-like test, which will include current working directory.